# Multiple proposed answers to a single question

Tags: discussion, answers

If a question is asked, whereby you have a number of suggested answers, is it preferred that you post multiple actual answers, or large answer with separated section headers?

### Version 1 Solution

---

*some content here*

### Version 2 Solution

---

*some content here*

## P.S

My vote is towards multiple answers as this above can get cumbersome and also negates the usefulness of a vote towards the answer when...there are more than one in a single response. (e.g if one is great, the other is woeful which one am I upvoting)

Answer (score 6):

Multiple answers is the norm.

It allows people to down-vote your bad answers too ;-)

(but, if you have two good answers, it allows you to amplify the rep gains too).